# Implementing Drop down list in c# using MVC-spark

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, spark-view-engine

- Controller Code:

  List Months = new List();

  ```
          Months.Add("Jan");
          Months.Add("Feb");

      ViewData["Months"] = new SelectList(Months);
  ```
- View Code:

${Html.DropDownList((SelectList)ViewData["Months"])}

**Error**: **Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList' to 'string'**

Comment: What is `List Months = new List();`?  I don't think that's valid c#

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty clear, it states that it expects a type of string and you are passing a SelectList make sure you use the correct overloads.

```
@Html.DropDownList("Months",selectList: ((SelectList)ViewData["Months"]))
```

Comment: I tried this but still getting the error : 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper does not contain a definition for 'DropDownList' and the best extension method overload 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownList(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, string, string)' has some invalid arguments
 error CS1503: Argument 3: cannot convert from 'object' to 'string''System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownList(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, string, string)' has some invalid arguments
 error CS1503: Argument 3: cannot convert from 'object' to 'string'

Comment: I unfortunately do not have the mvc-spark view engine installed. but i'm assuming that you are still not using the correct overloads. try to find one which allows you to pass a SelectList().

Comment: As per my understanding dropDownList do accept(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHe‌​lper, string) as the parameters and in our example ViewData acts as kind of HtmlHelper.

Comment: still Not working...Error: Cannot convert from 'object' to 'string'